# InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made in Robot Framework.

Tags: get, request, robotframework, insecure-connection

Hi I'm Using Robot Framework.

I'm trying to send a Get Request but I get the following warning

> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3-1.21.1-py2.7.egg\urllib3\connectionpool.py:852: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings  InsecureRequestWarning)

Has anyone had this problem? As I've searched for a solution one of the advice was to disable the warning, but how to do it?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: It is only a Warning, it is safe to ignore (unless security is really important). You could try `set PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0` or `set PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore:InsecureRequestWarning`

Comment: Hi Helio,

Can you please specify, how do I do it? 
I mean where do I set the PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY to 0?

Comment: @Helio any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following test case runs perfectly, without showing the warning.
Please note the option `verify=true` on the `Create Session` keyword.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections
Library           String
Library           RequestsLibrary
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Get Requests
    [Tags]    get
    Create Session    google    http://www.google.com    verify=true
    Create Session    github    https://api.github.com    verify=true
    ${resp}=    Get Request    google    /    timeout=5
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
    ${resp}=    Get Request    github    /users/bulkan    timeout=5
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
    Dictionary Should Contain Value    ${resp.json()}    Bulkan Evcimen
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Session along with `verify=true`, by default it's `verify=false`

`Create Session    test_session    http://www.example.com    **verify=true**`